# Modular python test grade

Tags: python, modular

so heres my code so far

```
def main():

     grade1=int(input('Enter test score: '))
     grade2=int(input('Enter test score: '))
     grade3=int(input('Enter test score: '))
     grade4=int(input('Enter test score: '))
     grade5=int(input('Enter test score: '))

     average = calc_average(grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5)
     print('Your average score is ', average)




def calc_average(grade1,grade2,grade3,grade4,grade5):

    average_score = (grade1+grade2+grade3+grade4+grade5)/5
    return average_score

def determine_grade(score):

    if 90 <= grade <= 100:
        return 'A'      
    elif 80 <= grade <= 89:
        return 'B'
    elif 70 <= grade <= 79:
        return 'C'
    elif 60 <= grade <= 69:
        return 'D'
    else:
        return 'F'

main()
```

I'm stuck right now because i need the output to look like this:

```
Enter test score: 90
The letter grade is: A
Enter test score: 80
The letter grade is: B
Enter test score: 70
The letter grade is: C
Enter test score: 60
The letter grade is: D
Enter test score: 50
The letter grade is: F
The average is: 70.0
```

idk how to go about having it show the letter grade after each test score is entered. Can anyone lend me a hand?

Comment: Based on your current design, you just need to call the `determine_grade` function after every user input and print the result. You seem to know how to call functions and handle their result. So, what are you having difficulty with exactly?

Comment: Think about using a loop rather than repeating the code 5 times. That way you could easily change it be ask for an any number of grades and you will only need to call `input` and `determine_grade` in one place. You could make `calc_average` accept a list and it will be able to handle nay number of grades.

Comment: @idjaw ive tried everything and i don't know how how to call it properly lol. ive had a long day

Comment: @polskiebmw Can you show what you have tried that failed, to help explain to you why what you were doing did not work?

Comment: @idjaw well under each grade i put print determine_grade(). i also did print ("the letter grade is: " + str determine_grade) and that didnt work. im just stuck cause i guess my professor didnt explain this to too well lol

Comment: @polskiebmw Did you actually pass the grade to `determine_grade`? For example, after your first entry for grade 1, did you do `print(determine_grade(grade1))`?

Comment: @idjaw no i didn't do any other thosse

Comment: @polskiebmw Try that...

Comment: @idjaw so put the print(determine_grade(grade1)) under every input. but how do i pass the grade to determine_grade?

Comment: @polskiebmw Remember after each input you are inputting the respective grade. So after you get `grade1=int(input('Enter test score: '))`, you call `print(determine_grade(grade1))` on the next line. Then, you are doing `grade2=int(input('Enter test score: '))`, so now you call `print(determine_grade(grade2))`. Note that now you are doing `grade2`. And just continue with that pattern.

Comment: @idjaw just did that and i got this error:     NameError: name 'grade' is not defined

Comment: @polskiebmw Yes. Because inside your `determine_grade` you are using `grade` to compare, but you declared `score` as the argument in your function. So, the easiest thing to not change too much code in your function, is change the `score` you used in your function definition to `grade`. So you should have `def determine_grade(grade):`

Comment: @idjaw thank you so much! i noticed i had score so i changed it to determine_grade(grade1,grade2,grade3... and it didnt work.

Comment: @polskiebmw You *really* need to think very carefully about what it is you are trying to do now. Please take your time and think. I gave you everything you need to get this working. I don't know why you are trying to put all the grades in the determine_grade function. You defined your function to take one argument. Slow down and think about it carefully.

Comment: @idjaw its how my professor wants it set up. i cant explain it either lol

Comment: @polskiebmw then you really need review your assignment carefully. Because based on the code you showed and all the explaining I provided, that should have fixed your problem.